# Approach to send push notifications via GCM to Android devices using WebView (JavaScript + PHP)?

Tags: javascript, php, android, android-studio, notifications

I want to send push notifications to Android devices. I'm using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) and I just implemented it with the beginner guide.

So I thought I will have two types of notifications:

1) Notification to all users

2) Notification to specific users on specific events via Ajax

---

So I've stored the GCM Registration Token in a variable creating a get-method in `RegistrationIntentService` this way:

```
private String gcmToken = RegistrationIntentService.getToken();
```

And pass that value to this Javascript method:

```
    @JavascriptInterface
    public String showToken() {
        return gcmToken;
    }
```

I tested to output the variable this way in JavaScript and it worked:

```
function init(){
    var val = Android.showToken();
    alert(val);
}
```

Now I'm thinking that these GCM Registration Tokens can expire and change. So first I don't want that this token will be checked all the time on the same device. Should I use a session for that in JavaScript? Then I wanted to store every token in my MySQL database using an Ajax-Call. So I could send notifications to all devices that installed my app.

Then if specific events occur and users are registered I want to store their GCM Registration Token too assigned to this specific user. So I can send notifications to specific users on specific events.

Is this whole way I described a good and practicable approach as a solution for my notification system?

I'm new to Java, so I'm more comfortable finding solutions using JavaScript. Maybe you'll give me the advice to use more Java for my case. That's why I'm asking this question to get feedback if my approach is legit.

Also Should I auto-delete my database for tokens that haven't been used after some weeks or is there a possibility they could return?